# How do you make a justified background color for a paragraph style in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles

In InDesign if I have a paragraph style and every time I use that style I want a "colored" box behind it justified to the column width. How would you suggest doing this? Currently it's been done manually with predefined "boxes" for 1-Line, 2-Line & 3-Line depending on how long the heading is. There has got to be a way to automate this though. Perhaps using some sort of programmatic style sheet?

All I could find was this "[Highlighting an Entire Paragraph with Color](http://indesignsecrets.com/highlighting-an-entire-paragraph-with-color.php)" which wouldn't work because the headings are centered but we want the background color to be the full column width.

Ideally, with a dynamic "height" so that it can be say 4pt above and below the text as well. Almost like padding would be if I were doing this on a website.

Comment: Why doesn't the Adobe tip work for you? This is exactly the solution I've used for years.

Comment: Adobe Tip? Do you mean the link I posted? If so I said why. Otherwise I'm not sure Adobe Tip is referring to?

Comment: erm... use the tip you post and in than the underline options, for width choose "Column".

Comment: Yes, by "Adobe tip" I meant "the link to InDesign Secrets which you posted." And Scott asked my followup question.

Comment: Okay thanks, I've learned InDesign predominately on the job and being as complex as it is I still have much to learn. I'll give this a shot tomorrow. If one of you wants to make your response an actual answer with the "Column" part I'll accept it.

Comment: hmm I just gave this a shot and am not seeing where your Underline Option > Width > Column is. Could you please let me know.

Comment: I like to use the table solution. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6591/highlighting-text-in-adobe-indesign/6592#6592

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of InDesign CC2015 a new feature was released called [Paragraph Shading](http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=2418567) to address this very topic.

For basic usage you can click the `Shading` button on your Paragraph Formatting area:

[image: Paragraph Shading]

You can also have some control over this through Paragraph Styles:

[image: Paragraph Shading Controls]

Comment: Nice - and yes, this took Adobe *too* long. And it's ... a half-hearted attempt. If you also want lines, you can look in to [DTPUtils great plugin](http://dtputils.com/products/view/1).

Answer (score 6):

I think the best way of doing so is coloring the text box, set the paddings and then create an object style. In the object style you can configure the default paragraph style to use.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

The column part is in the Rules section, not in the Underline Section.

I'm not sure the Underline option will achieve what you are looking for if the paragraphs you are styling are going to have different line counts/heights.

It would however work really well if you are going to use it for headers with one or two lines. You can just set up specific style sheets for each case.

Comment: If you add a rule above to this method and set both rule weights to a high number, and play around a bit with the Offset, it will work with paragraphs of varying sizes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to do this automatically and have InDesign CS6+ the only alternative is to create a script to achieve what you want.

If you're on a Mac you could always use AppleScript to record what you're doing and modify it accordingly to apply to every object in your project.  So this would extend further on Marcoslhc's answer.

If you're not on a Mac you can create the script in JavaScript which could run on either Mac or PC.  When I have time I will try to write the code out for you.

[Documentation on Scripting](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/indesign/documentation.html)

Comment: What did CS6+ add that older versions couldn't do this?

Comment: Nothing that I can tell at the moment other than all the documentation would appear to be extended on capabilities from CS6+ because all the documentation I am reading on is for CS6..  Until I can test on older versions I will stick with what the documentation is indicating.